# How to print quotes around a variable user inputted. Python

Tags: python

```
info = []
file = input("Enter a file ")

try:
    infile = open(file, 'r')

except IOError:
    print("Error: file" ,file, "could not be opened.")
```

if user enters file as filetest.txt,
This is my code.. I would like it to print Error: file "filetest.txt" could not be opened.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: please don't use `file` as a variable name (same goes for `list`, `dict` and pretty much all types)

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
print('Error: file "{}" could not be opened.'.format(file))
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> file = "filetest.txt"
>>> print('Error: file "{}" could not be opened.'.format(file))
Error: file "filetest.txt" could not be opened.
>>>
```

In Python, single quotes can enclose double quotes and vice-versa.  Also, here is a reference on [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

---

Lastly, I wanted to add that `open` defaults to read mode.  So, you can actually just do this:

```
infile = open(file)
```

However, some people like to explicitly put the `'r'`, so that choice is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

```
print("Error: file \"{}\" could not be opened.".format(file))
```

Be careful, however, that `file` is a built-in type in python. Per convention, your variable should be named `file_`

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotes with a backslash

```
myFile = "myfile.txt"
print("Error: file \"" + myFile + "\" could not be opened.")
```

Prints:

```
Error: file "myfile.txt" could not be opened.
```